# Override a view definition programmatically

Tags: 7, views, importing-exporting

I want to override a view definition programmatically (using the code that I get from "view export" in the views admin pages).

I've found examples for creating views using views_new_view(), but nothing on modifying views definition programmatically. Are there any examples / tutorials on this ?

Can I do this with views_get_view($name) / views_save_view() ?

Comment: Look at [Views hooks](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/group/views_hooks/7) and $view->add_item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got to a working solution :

```php
$my_view_name = 'my_test_view';

$view = views_get_view($my_view_name);
if ( $view ) {
  views_delete_view($view);
}

// ... code from view export UI ... 

$view->save();
```

If the view exists already then I delete it before recreating it.

Then I throw in the code taken from the views export UI, and add right after a `$view->save();`

And that does it.